# Invalid Namespace error - Adobe Air Extension Android Build

Tags: android, air, adobe, flex4.6, air-native-extension

I have been trying to create a sample demo to create adobe air extension in android.

My setup info is,

Flash builder 4.7,
AIRSDK - 19.0
Flex SDK 4.6
I am using mac OSx Yosamite.

Well, I have created the SWC with the AIRSDK 19.0 and created the ANE from that.

I have also created the Flex mobile project and done the integration as per this tutorial,
[Developing and using Adobe AIR native extensions for Android devices](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html)

I have integrated the ANE also, But the problem is in,
'properties -> Flex Building Packaging -> Google Android -> Native Extension' if i check the 'Package' checkbox than at build time it gives me this error,
`Invalid namespace 302`

if i remove this than error doesnot come but at runtime it is not able to find any native classes of my .jar,

I have set the 'merge into code' option in 'Flex Build Path' tab in properties and set the SWC Folder path.

I have been stuck to this from like days,
Please anyone can help.
Let me know if you want anymore details about this.
Thanks in Advance for every help.